# how to display a long label text inside panelcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

how to display a full label text ? the label is inside the panel control

[image]
the result is

[image]

what property or event should i use ? and i don't want the text remaining text became a newline

Comment: What exactly is the result you expect? The whole text seems too long to fit inside that panel on one line, so what should it look like? seems the only way is to choose a smaller `Font` for the `Label`.

Comment: yep , iknow. i want the output of label display all text breaking through the panel control. if i small the font its too small hard to read.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: the 2nd image on label display Delete (Ctrl+D)